# como hacer ajuste de linea en la ventana del editor de Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hola mi gente tengo una consulta como puedo hacer en Android Studio el ajuste de lineas para que  las lineas de código se ve han ajustada , en la ventana del editor de código

le agradecería si me ayudan en este punto.

gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te refieres al formato de código, si es así, existen dos shortcuts muy buenos que te ayuda, en realidad uno solo pero comparto el otro que también s util.

El primero se le conoce ( según la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)) como "Volver a formatear código" lo que hace es formatearlo el código según el guideline que estas manejando y también como esta configurado Android Studio. Ademas te permite ordenar tu código para sea más legible.

Control + Alt + L (windows,linux),  Comando + Opción + L(Mac)

El según es llamado "Optimizar importaciones", lo que hace es eliminar los imports que no estas utilizando. Muchas veces agregamos lineas de código que necesitan unos imports para que funcionen, pero si removemos esa linea no necesariamente se elimina la linea del import, entonces con esto puedes hacerlo.

Control + Alt + O (Windows, Linux)  Control + Opción + O (Mac)

Espero te ayude :)